# How to find the biggest and smallest of 50 random numbers without arrays?

Tags: java

Trying to print out the biggest and smallest of 50 random numbers in Java without arrays. It's not working, I'm pretty confused. Can someone help? Thanks!

```
public static void main() {
    int smallest = 0, biggest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        int randomNum = (int)(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        System.out.println(randomNum);
        smallest = randomNum;
        if (randomNum > biggest) {
            biggest = randomNum;
        }
        if (randomNum < smallest) {
            smallest = randomNum;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Smallest was " + smallest + ", biggest was " + biggest);
}
```

Comment: Please explain: in what ways is it "not working".

Comment: remove this `smallest = randomNum;`

Comment: "It's not working" - such a statement in itself is pretty useless since otherwise you'd not be asking. Please state in _what way_ it is not working, i.e. what do you expect and what do you get instead? Besides that stepping through your code with a debugger would reveal the problem quite fast.

Comment: You have put `smallest = randomNum` in the loop so the smallest got overwritten every loop.

Comment: Since Scott deleted his answer I'll repeat his point here: `int smallest = 0` will lead to problems as well since none of your random numbers will be smaller than 0. If you know you'll be checking at least one number (and in your case you know that) you should initialize `smallest` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `biggest` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. This sounds counter intuitive but that way your first number will always be smaller than `smallest` and bigger than `biggest` and from there it's a normal procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialise smallest to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and biggest to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, then in your loop you just have to remove `smallest = randomNum;` and it will work

Comment: Is there any other way to initialize them? Our teacher hasn't taught us about Integer.MAX/MIN_VALUE and it's highly unlikely that he would want us to do that.

Comment: Math.random() * 100 gives you a random between 0 and 100, so initialise your min to 100 and your max to 0.

Comment: But in general, when searching for min and max, always initialise them to the oposite maximum value, this way you know whatever value you will read, it will be smaller than you min and bigger than your max.

Answer (score -1):

I your problem is where is the main, it doesnt have 
    public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: So just try to change your public static void main() for public static void main(String[] args) , and then it will works

Comment: Eagle eye. But there is more jal j.

Comment: There was no mention of the program not running at all, so it seems the `main` signature is not an issue.  More likely, it's a logic problem in the implementation.